# Procedural maze remove old colliders

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, procedural-generation

I followed a tutorial on making a procedural generated maze in unity using C# that when you click the mouse button, it generates a new maze.

However, when I generate a new maze everything looks right but the `MeshCollider` for the old maze mesh is still in place, in addition to the new maze `MeshCollider` making numerous invisible walls.

How would I clear the old `MeshCollider`s in my script, so that they are removed and only the newly generated mesh remains?

**Initial maze image**

[image: Initial maze image]

**Second maze image**

[image: Second maze image]

Each maze, after the first, has the old `MeshCollider`s represented by the green outline and it looks like it is just making new `MeshCollider`s and not replacing the old one with a new one. I thought I could fix this by setting the mesh and `MeshCollider` to null, then new mesh at the beginning of each new maze generation, but it does nothing:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Mesh_Generator : MonoBehaviour {

public SquareGrid squareGrid;
public MeshFilter walls;
public MeshFilter cave;

public bool is2D;

List<Vector3> vertices;
List<int> triangles;

Dictionary<int,List<Triangle>> triangleDictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<Triangle>> ();
List<List<int>> outlines = new List<List<int>> ();
HashSet<int> checkedVerticies = new HashSet<int> ();

public void GenerateMesh(int[,] map, float squareSize){
    triangleDictionary.Clear ();
    outlines.Clear ();
    checkedVerticies.Clear ();

    squareGrid = new SquareGrid (map, squareSize);

    vertices = new List<Vector3> ();
    triangles = new List<int> ();

    for (int x = 0; x < squareGrid.squares.GetLength (0); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < squareGrid.squares.GetLength (1); y++) {
            TriangulateSquare (squareGrid.squares [x, y]);
        }
    }

    Mesh mesh = null;
    mesh = new Mesh ();

    cave.mesh = mesh;

    mesh.vertices = vertices.ToArray ();
    mesh.triangles = triangles.ToArray ();
    mesh.RecalculateNormals ();
    if (!is2D) {
        CreateWallMesh ();
    }
}


void CreateWallMesh(){

    CalculateMeshOutLines ();

    List<Vector3> wallVerticies = new List<Vector3> ();
    List<int> wallTriangles = new List<int> ();
    Mesh wallMesh = new Mesh ();
    float wallHeight = 5;

    foreach (List<int> outline in outlines){
        for (int i = 0; i < outline.Count -1; i ++){
            int startIndex = wallVerticies.Count;
            wallVerticies.Add (vertices [outline [i]]); // left vertex
            wallVerticies.Add (vertices [outline [i+1]]); // right vertex
            wallVerticies.Add (vertices [outline [i]] - Vector3.up * wallHeight); // bottom left vertex
            wallVerticies.Add (vertices [outline [i+1]] - Vector3.up * wallHeight); // bottom right vertex

            wallTriangles.Add (startIndex + 0); //triangle 1
            wallTriangles.Add (startIndex + 2);
            wallTriangles.Add (startIndex + 3);

            wallTriangles.Add (startIndex + 3); //triangle 2
            wallTriangles.Add (startIndex + 1);
            wallTriangles.Add (startIndex + 0);
        }
    }
    wallMesh.vertices = wallVerticies.ToArray ();
    wallMesh.triangles = wallTriangles.ToArray ();
    walls.mesh = wallMesh;


    MeshCollider wallCollider = walls.gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider> ();
    wallCollider = null;
    wallCollider = new MeshCollider ();
    wallCollider.sharedMesh = wallMesh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.Clear.html), you should call `Mesh.Clear` "before rebuilding triangles array."

```
mesh = new Mesh ();
cave.mesh.Clear();
cave.mesh = mesh;
```

Comment: I think I found the source of the problem, what is happening is that in my map generator script it calls on the program listed above which creates a MeshCollider 

`MeshCollider wallCollider = walls.gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider> ();`


what I need to do is have this only happen the first time and not happen on each successive click